# Is there a systemd equivalent for user sessions?

Tags: systemd, init

There are many times when I'd like to have a certain daemons run when a user logs in and killed when a user logs out. I'd like these daemons to be restarted if the daemon exits unexpectedly and I'd like a handy way to view the daemon status and what not. I want the daemon process to be owned by the user.

Basically, I want `systemd` and `systemctl`, but for sessions and not for the system. Is there such a thing? I'd imagine this is already part of `systemd`, but I haven't found anything regarding it. Usually folks recommend adding services to `~/.profile`, but this seems like a really poor init system.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  There is a user mode which I believe is for just what you describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, systemd has a user service manager which takes care of user-scoped services. You can control it using the same [`systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) commands you’d apply to system services, but with an extra `--user` option.